# How to pull PHP function every second in JS/Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I am working with the Highcharts (see: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) API for a dynamic updating graph to reflect sever load on my webpanel.

I have coded a PHP function that will get the current load data every time the function is ran; lets call this `get_server_cpu_usage()`.

My JS code should pull this data every second by using JS so that is supplies the data for the graph, however for some reason it seems that the data isn't being pulled each second and I am only getting one value, causing the live graph to flatline.

JS with PHP function being called:

```
events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = <?php echo get_server_cpu_usage(); ?>;
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
```

I was wondering if I was doing something wrong and how I could get the function to echo the data every time it is pulled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's because JS & PHP can't interact the way you're doing it now. You will need to run an ajax request to a php script that returns the `y` value from your `get_server_cpu_usage()` function.

Comment: You need to remember that php is serverside code and that js is client side code. You cannot call serverside functions directly from js (not in the way you are trying to do anyway). You will need to do as Darren has said and expose a php function via ajax that is consumed by javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just can't run php-code clientside using javascript like that. What you need is a ajax-call to pull the data. For instance by using jQuery.

```
    events: {
    load: function () {

        // set up the updating of the chart each second
        var series = this.series[0];
        setInterval(function () {
            $.get(
                'get_server_cpu_usage.php',
                function(result) {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = result;
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }
            )
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

in your project, create a php-file (in this case get_server_cpu_usage.php) that returns the result of get_server_cpu_usage();

Comment: You should also possibly include an ajax example to achieve the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to Ajax and jQuery so if you could provide and example of the function that supplies "result" that would be much appreciated.